# the meaning of いかをとる

Tags: translation, meaning

What is the meaning of

> いかをとる

(line 5)?

I tried to juggle with the meanings of いか and とる, meanings that I knew about or I found about later on (http://jisho.org/search/ika), but I still cannot make sense of their meaning together.
Is this an idiom?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's literally "catching squid".  The mentioning of the boats should've helped you with the context.

In case you didn't know, squid is commercially caught by attracting them using lights at night.  Here's a [Google picture search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AB%E3%80%80%E6%BC%81&biw=1608&bih=897&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPr47auv_JAhVY1WMKHXVQCl8Q_AUICCgB&dpr=0.9#imgrc=7215FJLndslzVM%3A).